# Foundation 5 text box not responding

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

The text boxes load fine and look great, but you can't click and select text.  You can click the textbox and the cursor moves to the first position, but nothing else.  For some reason the mouse isn't working in the controls, but the keyboard is.

These are dynamically created text boxes based on the number of rows from the DB.  Also, the user can click a spiffy + image to add additional rows.  I'm using F5 and also a sortable plugin.

HTML:

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-10 small-centered columns" id="Ingredients">
      <ul id="sortable-with-handles" class="sortable list">
        <li><div class='row'><div class='small-12 large-12 small-centered columns'><div class='row'>
  <div class='small-3 large-1 columns'>Sort</div>
  <div class='small-3 large-4 columns'>Ingredient</div>
  <div class='small-2 large-2 columns'>Dept</div>
  <div class='small-3 large-4 columns'>Shopping List</div>
  <div class='small-1 large-1 columns'><img src='./images/green_add.png' id='add_row' height='25' width='25' title='Add Another Row' /></div>
</div></div></div></li>
<li data-id=1><div class='row'><div class='small-12 large-12 small-centered columns' id='ingredients1'><div class='row'>
  <div class='small-3 large-1 columns'><img id='sort_1' class='handle' src='./images/sort-icon.png' /></div>
  <div class='small-3 large-4 columns'><input type='text' id='ingr_1' name='ingr_1' value='1 (12 ounce) jar Franks Red Hot Buffalo Sauce' /></div>
  <div class='small-2 large-2 columns'><select id='dept_1' name='dept_1' style='font-size:75%;' class='medium'>
<option value='0' style='font-size:8pt;'>Choose...</option>
  <div class='small-3 large-4 columns'><input type='text' id='shop_1' name='shop_1' value='1 (12 ounce) jar Franks Red Hot Buffalo Sauce' /></div>
  <div class='small-1 large-1 columns'><img src='./images/delete.png' id='delete_row_1' height='25' width='25' title='Remove Ingredient' /></div>
</div></div></div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
```

I'm including a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was turned out to be malformed html - I believe in my case, I had a `<div class="row">` that was nested improperly.  Looking at your code, it appears you are missing a closing div on your dropdown.

`<div class='small-2 large-2 columns'>
    <select id='dept_1' name='dept_1' style='font-size:75%;' class='medium'>
    <option value='0' style='font-size:8pt;'>Choose...</option>
<!-- missing closing div -->

<div class='small-3 large-4 columns'><input type='text' id='shop_1' name='shop_1' value='1 (12 ounce) jar Franks Red Hot Buffalo Sauce' />
</div>`